# Error with JUnit testing failure condition with Custom Exception

Tags: java, junit

I am writing a test case for the Rest Controller for an error condition and when I set expected exception to Exception.class the test runs with no errors. When I change the expected exception to CustomException.class, the test fails with assertion error

Here is my Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class CustomController<CustomFieldRequest customFieldRequest, CustomField customField> {
    @PutMapping(path = "/{customFieldId}",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML_VALUE})
    public CustomField updateCustomField(@PathVariable String customFieldId, @RequestBody CustomFieldRequest customFieldRequest) throws CustomException {
        customFieldRequest.setAuthorId(getUser());
        customFieldRequest.setId(customFieldId);
        return CustomService.updateCustomeField(customFieldRequest);
    }
}
```

Here is my service class:

```
@Service
public class CustomServiceImpl implements CustomService {
    @Override
    public CustomField updateCustomeField(CustomFieldRequest customFieldRequest) throws CustomException {

    }
}
```

Here is my custom exception class:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {
    public CustomException(final String  message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public CustomException(final String  message, final Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

Here is my test class:

```
public class CustomControllerTest {
    private CustomService customService = Mockito.mock(CustomService.class);

    @Test(expected=Exception.class)
    public void updateCustomFieldThrowsException() throws CustomException {
        //exception.expect(Exception.class);
        CustomFieldRequest request = getRequest();

        when(customService.updateCustomeField(request)).thenThrow(Exception.class);
        //customController.updateCustomField(request.getId(), request);
    }
}
```

As mentioned above if I change my expected exception to CustomException.class in the test like below:

```
    @Test(expected=CustomException.class)
    public void updateCustomFieldThrowsException() throws CustomException {
        //exception.expect(Exception.class);
        CustomFieldRequest request = getRequest();

        when(customService.updateCustomeField(request)).thenThrow(CustomException.class);
        //customController.updateCustomField(request.getId(), request);
    }
```

I see the test failing with `java.lang.AssertionError`. I tried the @Rule annotation(shown commented above).

Comment: Your test method seems incomplete (the code you show never invokes the update custom field if I'm not mistaken). You can get better insight in the exceptions thrown if you use, e.g., [AssertJ Exception Assertions](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#exception-assertion) instead of just `@Test(expected=...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a default constructor for `CustomException` or create the exeception in your test like this: `new CustomException("")`

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why you think think this solves the problem?